# simulating touch using ADB

Tags: android, touch, adb

I am trying to send touch events using batch files (.bat) and the adb shell.

I tried to re-send events I get from the adb shell getevents, and it doesn't work even though the command passes without errors.
Any ideas?

How do I simulate a touch-event and release-event on a given (x,y) coordinate using the ADB shell?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Since it seems to change depending on the Android version, I suggest you to follow these instructions :

1. Start dump motion event you need to reproduce:

   ```
   ~$ adb shell getevent | grep event2
   ```

   `grep` is very useful to filter output.
2. Do motion event you want to reproduce;
3. Then just convert all values from hex in dump to decimal values! :)

---

To find what eventX is working for you do following:

1. Start terminal and type:

   ```
   ~$ adb shell getevent
   ```

You will see quickly moving traces with for example /dev/input/event4 ......

2. Touch screen once

You must see between event4 few eventX and these eventX right in the moment of the touch

will be yours input interface for reproducing motion events! :)

[Source](http://softteco.blogspot.com/2011/03/android-low-level-shell-click-on-screen.html).

Comment: Please provide a complete answer, instead of just a link. Links can go away, change, etc, so the answer will be unusable.

Comment: That link has been updated to include the following for Android 2.2+ (Much easier!)

"adb shell input tap x y"

Answer (score 10):

I managed to emulate the event on sony xperia LT26i
by using

```
adb shell getevent | grep event2
```

to capture input and then converting all values from hex to decimal,
and by putting the generated sequence in a shellscript

```
adb shell sendevent /dev/input/event2 3 57 23710
adb shell sendevent /dev/input/event2 3 53 329
adb shell sendevent /dev/input/event2 3 54 1183 
adb shell sendevent /dev/input/event2 3 52 0
adb shell sendevent /dev/input/event2 0 0 0
adb shell sendevent /dev/input/event2 3 57 4294967295
adb shell sendevent /dev/input/event2 0 0 0
```

I figured from posts in linked forum that line 2 and 3 are setting X and Y position
the next 2 lines are touch press and the bottom 2 lines are touch release, I havent figured out what the first line does yet but it is needed for it to work.
I hope this is useful to you