# How programmatically click on Android "back button" from application?

Tags: android, kotlin

How programmatically click on Android "back button" from an application? Is it possible?
Like `adb shell input keyevent 4`

Comment: what you mean by application ?

Comment: If you are asking about touch event from ADB then see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18924968/using-adb-to-access-a-particular-ui-control-on-the-screen ..

Comment: onBackPressed()?

Comment: override fun onBackPressed() {
  super.onBackPressed()
}

Comment: Thank you. But onBackPressed for Back button. What if i want click and another buttons?

Answer (score 1):

There is default method can be use for back press,

```
@Override 
public void onBackPressed() { return; }
```

By Overriding this method you can access Back button grammatically. Usually, Back button is already called as default method in android but backPressed can be useful while using navigation Drawer or menu