# Grant android VPN permission via command line using adb

Tags: android, adb, vpn

I am able to grant accessibility permission using adb. Please see the command below

```
adb shell settings put secure enabled_accessibility_services <package_name><package-name>.AccessibilityServiceName
```

Is there a way to grant VPN permission via adb too?

Answer (score 0):

TLDR: You cannot use that command, and you cannot use another permission based command either.

### Working solution to automate pressing this button

The only solution I could think of is it to use `adb` to press the `OK` button on the Connection request alert dialog generated by the OS:

```
adb shell uiautomator dump /sdcard/Download/view.xml
adb pull /sdcard/Download/view.xml
```

Observe the file, it contains the alert dialog. Specifically, <kbd>OK</kbd> is:

```
<node index="2" text="OK" resource-id="android:id/button1" class="android.widget.Button" package="com.android.vpndialogs" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="true" enabled="true" focusable="true" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[564,2040][1008,2148]" /></node>
```

[Press it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50027374/7365866):

```
coords=$(perl -ne 'printf "%d %d\n", ($1+$3)/2, ($2+$4)/2 if /text="OK"[^>]*bounds="\[(\d+),(\d+)\]\[(\d+),(\d+)\]"/' view.xml)
adb shell input tap $coords
```

[image]

Mostly inspired from [Apricot's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50027374/7365866).

---

You might have tried: `adb shell pm grant com.example.package_name android.permission.CONTROL_VPN`, but that won't work.

```
Exception occurred while executing 'grant':
java.lang.SecurityException: Package com.example.package_name has not requested permission android.permission.CONTROL_VPN
    at com.android.server.pm.permission.BasePermission.enforceDeclaredUsedAndRuntimeOrDevelopment(BasePermission.java:453)
    at com.android.server.pm.permission.PermissionManagerService.grantRuntimePermissionInternal(PermissionManagerService.java:1549)
    at com.android.server.pm.permission.PermissionManagerService.grantRuntimePermissionInternal(PermissionManagerService.java:1503)
    at com.android.server.pm.permission.PermissionManagerService.grantRuntimePermission(PermissionManagerService.java:1495)
    at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerShellCommand.runGrantRevokePermission(PackageManagerShellCommand.java:2339)
    at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerShellCommand.onCommand(PackageManagerShellCommand.java:261)
    at android.os.BasicShellCommandHandler.exec(BasicShellCommandHandler.java:98)
    at android.os.ShellCommand.exec(ShellCommand.java:44)
    at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService.onShellCommand(PackageManagerService.java:26885)
    at android.os.Binder.shellCommand(Binder.java:965)
    at android.os.Binder.onTransact(Binder.java:839)
    at android.content.pm.IPackageManager$Stub.onTransact(IPackageManager.java:5206)
    at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService.onTransact(PackageManagerService.java:5357)
    at android.os.Binder.execTransactInternal(Binder.java:1195)
    at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:1159)
```

**You have to request the permission using [`prepare(context)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/VpnService#prepare(android.content.Context)).**

---

### Do you understand what `settings` command is doing?

It's not for *permissions*.

`enabled_accessibility_services` is used to change the Settings (in the Settings app) to enable a specific accessible service declared in an application. In this case, this accessibility service still needs the `"android.permission.BIND_ACCESSIBILITY_SERVICE"` permission. It cannot add it through ADB.

There is no equivalent for VPN permissions within this, this command doesn't give **permissions** to applications, it configures the OS **settings**.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way but without adb command line,

**It's easy; you can use this to click 'OK' on the VPN permission dialog.:**

```
UiDevice.getInstance(InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation()).findObject( UiSelector().text("OK")).click()
```

Use this `implementation 'androidx.test.uiautomator:uiautomator:2.2.0'` to implement UiDevice.