# How to disable Eco-Mode on TeamViewer Host with ADB

Tags: android, adb, teamviewer

I have to remotely set up a large amount of Android devices with TeamViewer Host. I currently use ADB to install a TeamViewer Host .apk as well as a QuickSupport Add-On .apk. The issue I am facing now is that Eco-Mode is enabled, and I have do disable it manually for every device. Is there a way for me to do this with ADB also? Or alternatively is there a TeamViewer settings file I can update so Eco-Mode isn't on by default?

[Teamviewer Eco-Mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i0AQW.png)

Comment: Is "Eco-Mode" a setting of Teamviewer or of the device?

Comment: It is a TeamViewer setting. It is essentially a power saving feature. See the image I attached in the original post

Comment: Then I would ask TeamViewer support, as you are a customer they should be able to answer this question.

Comment: From your image, it seems you can only change this setting through the GUI. How many devices (roughly) do you need to do this for?

Comment: @Robert, I have asked TeamViewer support. They said I should ask on a ADB related forum. I presume they are not too familiar with the method I'm using. Also, they said there is not a setting that I can change to have it auto disabled when installing

Comment: @huytc I do this for no more than 60 devices at a time. And thusfar I have done roughly 500 devices

Answer (score 1):

So, from your comment, you need to change this setting for quite a lot of devices (around 500). I don't have time to create a detailed solution for you, but I'll suggest these two approaches.

## Approach 1: Scripting

Use `adb` to grab coordinates and simulate touches. Write a script to automate the process.

See [Using ADB to access a particular UI control on the screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18924968/using-adb-to-access-a-particular-ui-control-on-the-screen).

**Edit:** [Culebra GUI](https://github.com/dtmilano/AndroidViewClient/wiki/Culebra-GUI) seems to make your life a lot easier should you take this approach.

### Pros

- Pretty straightforward.

### Cons

- Quite tedious when your flow is complex (kind of a personal opinion, so take this with a grain of salt).

## Approach 2: AccessibilityService

Utilize Android's [AccessibilityService](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityService). You will need to write an Android app that has an `AccessibilityService` and bulk install it on the devices (via `adb` or any other means).

### Pros

- Powerful API.
- Doesn't require `adb`.

### Cons

- Needs to install your app on the devices.
- Lots of boilerplate code.
- `AccessibilityService` needs to be enabled manually. This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10061154/how-to-programmatically-enable-disable-accessibility-service-in-android/38939299#38939299) shows how to automate it, but I have yet to test if it works.

## TL;DR

- Write a shell script that uses `adb` for simple, one-off operations.
- Use `AccessibilityService` for more complex use cases.

Comment: Totally agree. Script creating can be automated or simplified using [Culebra-GUI](https://github.com/dtmilano/AndroidViewClient/wiki/Culebra-GUI)

Comment: @DiegoTorresMilano Thanks for the suggestion. Looks really interesting. Might give it a go someday since I work with a lot of Android automation myself.