# Detecting the Android keyboard with Calabash?

Tags: android, keyboard, automated-tests, calabash, calabash-android

I am writing a series of automated tests for an android app using calabash-android and I need to be able to detect whether the android system keyboard is visible or not and (if possible) read some of the keys (i.e. if the return key says `Done` instead of `Next` or `Enter`). I know there is the `keyboard_visible?` commands for iOS but I have not been able to find anything similar for android.

Has anyone built their own functions to handle these instances?

Comment: I have not tried this but perhaps you can check the height of your views to see if keyboard is shown?

Comment: I saw something about that. I was hoping for a more definite solution.

Comment: Try to check for a element in keypad is displayed or not to make sure your device keypad is visible .. ex element_exists("* marked:'View_Name') . View_Name could be anything from your keypad

Comment: That doesn't seem to work for me, although I don't know if there are special names for the keyboard components.

Answer (score 1):

there is a way to take a dump of the screens current contents on android using a tool called uiautomator from the android SDK.   You can then check this for whatever you need to.  It's not the most elegant solution but it might just work.  Have a look at this post.

[Calabash handling "Complete action using" dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25016094/calabash-handling-complete-action-using-dialog/25059119#25059119)

Comment: The uiautomator does not capture the components or properties of the keyboard. It only shows you a screen shot of it with all the components underneath it, which isn't very helpful when trying to find it in an automated test.

Comment: @Metomorphose Hmm apologies, I really expected the keyboard to be included in the output with some options set that you could assert on.  I've had a bit more of a look and this thread - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5457486/is-there-a-way-to-tell-if-the-soft-keyboard-is-shown/24105062#24105062 has an answer that is working for me    `adb shell dumpsys window InputMethod | grep "mHasSurface"` This should return true or false at the beginning (ish) of the return value.  Not too sure about checking for specific buttons.

Answer (score 0):

```
windown_input_method = %x(adb -s #{ENV['ADB_DEVICE_ARG']} shell dumpsys window InputMethod | grep "mHasSurface")
windown_input_method.include?("isReadyForDisplay()=true")
```

This one returns true if keyboard is visible and false if not
ENV['ADB_DEVICE_ARG'] is environmental variable holding the device id of your android device connected. If you always run on one device, simply

```
windown_input_method = %x(adb shell dumpsys window InputMethod | grep "mHasSurface")
windown_input_method.include?("isReadyForDisplay()=true")
```

will do