# How to click ok Button on alert box in calabash android

Tags: calabash, calabash-android

When i login to my app it will ask me for permissions to access camera roll and notifications i need to click OK button on those Popups . can any one tell me how to write step definitions for that?

Answer (score 0):

Calabash 0.5.15 installs your app with all permissions already granted. Can you upgrade?

https://github.com/calabash/calabash-android/blob/master/changelog/0.5.15.md

If this isn't an option for some reason, there is a hacky way that you can work out the buttons location and send a touch event using adb.  I really don't recommen this though - [Calabash handling "Complete action using" dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25016094/calabash-handling-complete-action-using-dialog)